# "I hardly/highly doubt it"

Tags: word-usage

I always thought "I hardly doubt it" was a correct sentence, but it seems that it isn't.
I do find a lot of occurrences though.

Should it be "I highly doubt it"?

I know the difference between *hardly* and *highly*, but just wanted to know if it can be used in this context. 
[This](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090531183356AApVVuM) made me doubt it (*pun intended*).

Comment: I highly doubt that you checked the difference between hardly and highly in a dictionary.

Comment: I don't understand why other peoples have such a strange formulaic idea of the English language. As though the combination of English words is constrained by some form of unknown formula. As long as when words fit together conform to acceptable grammar, English can be used to express the ordinary, the extraordinary, the zanny, the weird, the cute, the unusual, etc.

Comment: @Josh61 I highly recommend you trying to find the idiom "highly doubt it" vs "hardly doubt it" - it is very hard and NGRAM even shows "hardly doubt" is the more popular expression regardless of it being wrong.

Comment: @mplungjan - Hi, I don't get your point. The two expressions are not idioms and are both used and correct (see Jasper answer). But OP has actually improved his question now giving context.

Comment: As much an idiom as "I could care less" vs "I couldn't care less"

Comment: @mplungjan, no it's not at all like "could/couldn't care less". Both "hardly doubt" and "highly doubt" are grammatically AND semantically correct; they just happen to mean opposite things. "Could care less" is OK grammatically, but not semantically; nevertheless, for *some* people it's idiomatic. All of "couldn't care less", "hardly doubt", and "highly doubt" are idiomatic in standard English, but none of them are idioms.

Comment: @mplungjan The chart from Google Books Ngram Viewer wouldn't tell us anything in this case.  You'd have to read through the context of each example to determine whether the phrase is intended with the standard meaning or the way the OP suggests.  If you *can* find a fair number of examples that fit the OP's usage, it would be interesting to see!  If you did, then the next question would be whether to consider them a type of error.

Comment: @Josh61 My point was to "I highly doubt you checked..." - it is not easy. I tried. Martha - idiom/idiomatic close enough in my opinion to be an idiom since it is used in a way it was not ment to be.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> I hardly doubt it

means you doubt it only a little.

> I highly doubt it

means you doubt it a lot.

Both are grammatical but mean quite opposite things.

Comment: I'd suspect that the "hardly" form is usually a malapropism in actual usage.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard the term "I'd hardly doubt it"; you'd use that in case you were unsurprised were events to take a certain turn.

> "Do you reckon she'll come back?"
>
> "I'd hardly doubt it. It's not like she has a back-up plan."

You'd use "I highly doubt it" (note use of I/I'd) if you were dubious of the course of events.

> "Are the cookies ready yet?"
>
> "I highly doubt it, it only feels like five minutes."

Answer (score -3):

I do a lot of writing and I think in this case you have to think of the separate meanings of highly and hardly and put that with the doubt part.

"Highly doubt it" is the more preferable and, possibly more correct way, as it means the person really doubts what has been said (for example).

"Hardly doubt it" can be used but it has a slightly different meaning. Say someone (in a story) says they believe something is going to happen/certain outcome. The replier would say "I hardly doubt it" if they disagree/think the opposite.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So you're saying that "highly doubt it" means the person really doubts what has been suggested, and "hardly doubt it" means the person disagrees with what has been suggested?

Comment: yes, which sounds less complicated to the way i explained lol :)

Comment: That means that *hardly* is equivalent to *highly*, which is wrong, I'm afraid. They are almost exact opposites.

Comment: You mean "the more preferable" way as distinct from the merely preferable way?

Comment: Hardly preferable.